# Ширина видео css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Пытаюсь поставить видео на задний фон сайта. Нужно, чтобы при любой высоте окна видео занимало всю высоту, при этом обрезаясь по горизонтали. У меня вроде бы получилось, но снизу появилась полоса прокрутки и сам сайт стал шире, а когда окно уменьшается, полоса прокрутки увеличивается. Вот мой код

### html

```html
<div class="container-fluid page1">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto" poster="{% static 'vid/bg_poster.jpg' %}">
        <source src="{% static 'vid/bg.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

### css

```css
.page1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
.page1 > video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Вопрос: как обрезать лишнее?

Comment: min-width min-height 100% для видео  oveflow: hidden- блоку => если вилео не пропорционально отображается то добавить object-fit:cover

Comment: @MaximLensky overflow hidden не работает для элементов с position absolute

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvMzBxR - всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
.page1 > video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    min-width: 100%;
    -webkit-size: cover;
    -moz-size: cover;
    -o-size: cover;
    size: cover;
}
```